# how do I assign variable to html input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign variable to html input. here's what I have tried but it doesn't work.

`<input type=number>let x = 10</input>`

I want to assign variable to html input so I can use it later how can I do it.

Comment: it doesn't work like that, you have to reference the element in your js, then assign a value to it

Comment: use `javascript` for that, to set and get value to HTML input

Answer (score 0):

get the element of your input in your js, then assign a value to it like this

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
let x = 10;
input.value = x;
```

```html
<input type=number>
```

Comment: can't assign this way? `<input type="number" value="10">`

Comment: he sure can but the OP said he wanted to assign a variable to it